# Model meta option: app_label not being included when using db_table

Tags: django, django-models

I am using the Meta class option, `db_table` on my model class in order to format the table names within my Django app **accounts/models.py**. When I do this and run migrations (makemigrations then migrate), it doesn't carry along the app label (the app name is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` list). I want to get `<app_label>_<db_table>` formatted tables.

If I attempt to add the `app_label` option explicitly to the Meta class along with `db_table` it still isn't recognized as part of the migration plan and therefore never makes it to the database as `<app_label>_<db_table>`. Reference docs and Django version 2.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/

project/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
]
```

accounts/models.py

```
class PasswordAttempt(models.Model):
    attempt_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    security_id = models.ForeignKey(Security, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attempt_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts' # Shouldn't be necessary, but still doesn't work
        db_table = 'password_attempt'
```

accounts/migrations/001_initial.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

 ...# Other models

        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PasswordAttempt',
            fields=[
                ('attempt_id', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('attempt_count', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('security_id', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='accounts.Security')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'password_attempt',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Everything seems fine and dandy until I drop in `db_table` in the Meta class. Once that happens I am losing my app label for that table name. I am likely missing something obvious, but have been spinning my tires a bit here. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you do `db_table = 'accounts_password_attempt'`? And why are you setting it at all, since that would be the default?

Comment: I am expecting Django to behave as the docs indicate. The app_label should not need to be specified if it is in INSTALLED_APPS, even if it is, migrations are not picking it up. Hardcoding the app_label to the db_table  then assigning it to db_table option does not seem like the way to go. The default table name without meta options is `accounts_passwordattempt`, when I set `db_table = 'password_attempt'` I lose `accounts` and just get `password_attempt`.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the docs, if hardcoding is the only way to get the app label assigned (like other models without the db_table option specified) then so be it.